# Unable to configure font in XTerm

Tags: xterm

After a lot of mucking around Xterm, poring through reams of webpages I have thrown in the towel and realized that this isn't something I can figure out on my own.

**TrueType vs Bitmap**

1. Is the option `xterm*font` used to specify only bitmap fonts and is `*faceName` used only for TrueType fonts?
2. I'm using the commands `xlsfonts` and `fc-list` to find out the Bitmap and TrueType fonts that are installed. Is this correct?
3. I want to set the XTerm font to Ubuntu Mono. This is the output of `fc-list | grep -i ubuntu`

   ```
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=Bold Italic
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=BoldForPowerline
   Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=ItalicForPowerline
   ```

and I added `XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline`
 to my `~/.Xresources` and ran `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

`xrdb -query all` shows that `*faceName` is set to `Ubuntu Mono for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline`

However, this doesn't work. What am I missing/screwing up here?

Comment: The xterm man page recommends `fc-list :scalable=true:spacing=mono: family` which prints the font face name without the `style=...` annotation, and that's what you should give to xterm. The `spacing=mono` requirement helps you avoid inappropriate fonts (a terminal screen is a grid of characters, and variable width fonts look ridiculous when forced into a grid)

Comment: How do I find out what the family name is? I'm guessing it's "Ubuntu Mono" but just to be sure

Comment: I believe if you use the recommended `fc-list` command you get the family name exactly as you should use it.

Comment: Thanks, the exact `fc-list` command helped

Comment: There is a "Your Answer" box on this page, and that is there for you too to put your answer (and accept). If someone is in a hurry looking for a solution (s)he will not read to the bottom of your question to see that there is an answer hidden there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally figured out what's wrong just a couple of days ago after scrounging through multiple sources. Combining everyone's responses here:

Ubuntu Mono is a TrueType font and TrueType fonts require xterm to be compiled with FreeType library support. To check whether xterm has this, use the `ldd /path/to/xterm/binary` command and see if it says freetype in there. An alternate way is to see if xterm has the `-fa` option.

If your xterm has FreeType lib support, choose a

1. Bitmap fonts, by running `xfontsel -p` and use the exact string it prints upon exit.
2. TrueType fonts, using `fc-list :scalable=true:spacing=mono: family` and use the exact string it outputs.

Once you have the font name using one of the above steps, set it via `XTerm*faceName: <name of the font>`

If you install a new font, and it doesn't show up when you run one of the above commands, rebuild your font cache using `fc-cache -frv` and try again.

P.S. I used Ubuntu Mono patched font downloaded from [here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) I'm using `XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline`

Thanks to Wumpus Q. Wumbley and Thomas Dickey for their detailed responses.

Answer (score 5):

It is an old one, but for anyone coming here, the solution is:

```
XTerm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular
```

and if you want to see the change immediately then run:

```
xrdb -merge .Xresources

xterm
```

Answer (score 2):

This question was *first* posted to [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29809617/unable-to-configure-font-in-xterm), where [I answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29810362/4518274) a year ago, noting that the actual package did not provide the style `RegularForPowerline` (apparently OP was confused with some aspect of the output of `fc-list`:

> `fc-list` shows me `Regular` where you have `RegularForPowerline`.

Comment: Hello Thomas, thank you for responding there. I saw your comment about the `-fa` option and it helped me figure out why I wasn't seeing that option. My XTerm was missing FreeType library support.