# how to set xterm to have "Huge font" through .Xresources

Tags: fonts, xterm

This question is related to [Unable to configure font in XTerm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198010/unable-to-configure-font-in-xterm), however, I have not been able to get it to work.

I want to be able to have the Huge font enabled by default for me when I start xterm.

I have the following in my .Xresources:

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: MiscFixed:style=Huge
XTerm*faceSize: 10
XTerm*faceLabel: Huge
```

followed by `xrdb -merge .Xresources` but the Huge VT Option does not get invoked and I am still at the Default setting.

This does not do anything to get the xterm have "Huge" fonts. I also tried a bunch of things such as `XTerm*VTFonts: Huge` but to no avail. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: xterm won't handle `MiscFixed:style=Huge`; it expects a family name with an optional size (whether fontconfig does is a different matter).  There's no `faceLabel` resource, either.

Comment: The question may be about [this font](https://ba.maisfontes.com/huge-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the huge font when running xterm interactively, you can use an alias. I like the fonts selected from the FreeType library, `-fa default` and to control the size with `-fs <size>` for example

```
xterm -fa default -fs 16
```

and make an alias with it

```
alias xterm='xterm -fa default -fs 16'
```

If you like it, you can edit your configuration file for the shell, for bash `~/.bashrc`, and add the alias near the other aliases and save the file. Also for bash, run

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

to activate it in the current window or screen. Whenever you start a new shell, the alias will be available, type

```
xterm
```

and you get the font and size defined by the alias.

***Update by OP:***

The above is a great solution, and what I used to do in the past. However, following the above, I was able to go back and look at the manual. I searched -fs there and got the idea to the following Setting:

```
XTerm*renderFont: true
XTerm*faceName: MiscFixed
XTerm*faceSize: 16
```

in my .Xresources does the needful and is an alternative way, that is more in line with what I was looking for as an answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks to @sudodus, I have found my answer and edited the above answer. I intend accepting it once it is approved. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome @user3236841 :-) I'm glad that I could help you a bit on the way to find a good solution.