# Scaling default xterm font to "Large"

Tags: fonts, xterm, x-resources

In `xterm`, I would like to increase the default font size to the `font5/Font5/"Large"` option of the default VTFont. I've managed to do this manually with my mouse via the control menu so far, which is brilliant, but it can become quite a burden whenever I open a new xterm window. Hence, I would like to achieve the same by setting it as my default in my `.Xresources` file, so that every new xterm window opens in the "Large" font size by default instead of using the control menu.

Reading the man page and doing some further research online, I tried, in separate attempts: `xterm*font: font5`, `xterm*font: *-fixed-*-*-*-18-*` and `xterm*faceSize: 12.0` to achieve a similar outcome. Whilst the first try didn't work at all, in the latter two, the font is indeed increased but rather blurred when compared with what I can achieve through the control menu option. Surely, there must be a way!

- [How can I find the default (font) resource XTerm is using?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96962/how-can-i-find-the-default-font-resource-xterm-is-using)
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/how-to-increase-font-size-of-xterm-776352/
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm
- https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#how2_fsize
- [Configure unreadable, tiny, small, ..., huge Xterm fonts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332316/configure-unreadable-tiny-small-huge-xterm-fonts)

Edit: I have found a second way of increasing, decreasing and resetting the size of the default VTFont via `Ctrl+plus`/`Ctrl+minus`/`Ctrl+0`:

```
xterm*VT100.Translations: #override \
    Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key> 0: set-vt-font(d)
```

- http://futurile.net/2016/06/14/xterm-setup-and-truetype-font-configuration/

However, this method still requires manual handling every time I open a new xterm window. The search continues . . .

Comment: I suggest that you try one of the alternatives shown in [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668851/how-to-set-xterm-to-have-huge-font-through-xresources/668858#668858). Either use a free-type font via alias or use the .Xresources file to set the fixed font (or a free-type font).

Comment: Thanks @sudodus, I've tried both alternatives. The free-type example works, but I would prefer to keep the default fixed VTFont and 'MiscFixed' doesn't seem to be a recognised value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`initialFont`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:initialFont) resource to do this:

```
   initialFont (class InitialFont)
           Specifies which of the VT100 fonts to use initially.  Values
           are the same as for the set-vt-font action.  The default is
           "d", i.e., "default".
```

e.g.,

```
xterm*VT100.initialFont: 5
```

Comment: You can also test this out, before modifying your `.Xresources` file, using the `-xrm` option: `xterm -xrm 'xterm*VT100.initialFont:5'`. And merge them in via `xrdb -merge ~/.Xdefaults` or `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`, depending upon the file you happen to use.